# Typesetting a symbol with both a subscript and an exponent

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

Suppose I take the variable `$X_a$` and square it. To be clear, the `_a` is part of the variable's name, whereas the `^2` will denote the mathematical operation of squaring.

I could typeset this as

- `$X_a^2$`
- `$X_a{}^2$`
- `$(X_a)^2$`

Is there an accepted convention about which approach is best?

Comment: The most normal one is probably the first. Two is uncommon in the fields I work with. Third would probably be best if you are afraid your readers will not understand the first type

Comment: I’d also go for either the first or the third choice. The final choice should depend importantly on what exactly `X_a` denotes. Are there also variables named `X_b`, `X_c`, etc? Incidentally, if `X_a` were an n-tupel, I would write its inner product as `{X_a}’X_a`, to make sure that the transpose symbol is not placed directly above the letter `a`.